# How to I build/compile the latest FFmpeg snapshot for OS X?

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, homebrew

How do I compile FFmpeg for OS X in a way that is equivalent to the Homebrew release with these settings?

```
brew install ffmpeg --with-fdk-aac --with-ffplay --with-freetype --with-libass --with-libquvi --with-libvorbis --with-libvpx --with-opus --with-x265
```

I found this [tutorial on trac.ffmpeg.org](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/MacOSX), but I have these questions:

- Is the tutorial up-to-date and relevant for OS X El Capitan?
- Are all steps *really* needed, even compiling a custom version of Glib?
- How do I go about to install the libraries mentioned above (ffplay, x265, etc)?
- And basically; how do I build and install FFmpeg for usage on OS X?

Comment: Why not use homebrew?

Comment: There is a new filter I need to use (agate) which is not included with the current Homebrew release. It is only available in the snapshot/release packages.

Comment: I compiled my ffmpeg many years ago, maybe after Lion though.  I don't recall having to edit code to get glib to compile.  But, you *DO* need to install all of the required libraries, plus libraries for all of the encoders (MP3, etc.) that you want.  If you don't have any experience with `configure` and `make`, it could be a long road to getting ffmpeg to compile.  Try to see if someone on the agate website/forum/etc has a compiled copy, if you trust running someone else's code.  Maybe see if this site will do it: http://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/

Comment: From the guide you linked to, why not use Homebrew to install the dependencies, and then just compile ffmpeg?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use Homebrew to install the latest ffmpeg snapshot from github, try your command with the `--HEAD` flag, like so:

```
brew install --HEAD ffmpeg --with-fdk-aac --with-ffplay --with-freetype \
--with-libass --with-libquvi --with-libvorbis --with-libvpx --with-opus --with-x265
```

Answer (score 0):

After asking around a bit, I concluded that compiling ffmpeg by yourself isn't really necessary.

Binaries are provided here: https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/

The binary can be executed directly from the folder where it is located with this command (be sure to include the `./`):

```
./ffmpeg -i INPUT.AVI OUTPUT.AVI
```

or better yet, placed somewhere where it can be called with `$PATH` and the command `ffmpeg`.

However, this is not really an answer to the question of how to compile ffmpeg, so I will leave the question open.